# Disable privacy policy in shopware

Tags: shopware, privacy-policy

Is there a way to disable the checkbox + text in shopware 6 of the privacy notice?

have been checking the settings but no luck finding anything.

maybe by adding the twig file?

Answer (score 0):

No need to anwser anymore, this can be adjusted in the twig file
/ form-components/cms-element-form-privacy.html.twig

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).